# I am trying to read integer values from console in objective c

Tags: objective-c

When i m reading the first value it' not taking the value and keep going into loop. and when i press "esc" and "enter" then it is going to read second number but not taking the second number an program execution completes..

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    int firstNumber = 0,secondNumber = 0,result = 0;

    printf("\nEnter first number");
    scanf("%d", &firstNumber);

    printf("\nEnter second number");
    scanf("%d", &secondNumber);

    result = firstNumber+secondNumber;

    printf("\nResult is %d", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're using int you should use %i instead of %d.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, check it again! You can just slightly modify it to enter the number on the new lines

```
    int first = 0, second = 0, result = 0;
    printf("Enter the first number: \n");
    scanf("%d",&first);
    printf("Enter the second number: \n");
    scanf("%d",&second);
    result = first + second;
    printf("Result is: %d \n", result);
    cout << "\nEnd";
    return 0;
```